# How to solve a resolution error with npm?

Tags: npm, angular-cli

I am getting `npm resolution error` for many commands that I run with npm such as:

```
npm update
npm install
ng add @angular/material
```

The error prompt:

```
Could not resolve dependency:
peer @angular/common@"^12.0.0 || ^13.0.0-0" from @angular/cdk@12.2.2
node_modules/@angular/cdk
  @angular/cdk@"^12.2.2" from the root project
```

What does this mean? I cannot use `npm update` either. How should I solve this?

Also, adding `--legacy-peer-deps` at the end of the commands doesn't resolve the error.